# tsql connects to ODBC but Perl DBI gets an error

Tags: sql-server, perl, odbc, dbi, freetds

- Client is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS talking to an MS SQL Server 2005. Ubuntu has no registered domain. It's inside the local network as is the MS SQL Server.
- Perl 5.18.2 using DBI 1.63 and DBD::ODBC 1.52.
- Installed FreeTDS 0.92 (with TDS v4.2) and unixODBC 2.2.14.
- `isql DSN USERNAME PASSWD` at the command line also doesn't work. Perhaps I should start with that. I still get the same error which is `Unable to connect to data source (SQL-08001).`

My related config files:

```
2015-07-09 11:55:14 AM
NOTE: TDS version from tsql -C must go into freetds.conf and odbc.ini files

=========================================
/etc/odbcinst.ini:
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS 0.91 for Microsoft SQL Server 2005
#Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount = 1
#Threading = 2
fileusage = 1
dontdlclose = 1

=========================================
/etc/odbc.ini:
[ODBC Data Sources]
ResponseBDO = Response database desc in /etc/odbc/ini

[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS 0.91 driver
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so

[responsebdo]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = Response MSSQL 2005 ODBC driver
SERVER = sqlsvr.mydomain.com
PORT = 1433
USER = 'domain\domainuser'
Password = mypasswd
Database = r4w_004
# TDS_VERSION should be same as reported by 'tsql -C'.
TDS_Version = 4.2

[Default]
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Description = Default FreeTDS ODBC driver
SERVER = 10.20.30.40
USER = "domain\domainuser"
Database = r4w_4

=========================================
Relevant part of /etc/freetds/freetds.conf:
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same 
# name is found in the installation directory.  
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings, 
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".  
# 
[responsetds]
    #host = 10.20.30.40
    host = sqlsvr.mydomain.com
    port = 1433
    tds version = 4.2
    connect timeout = 20
    timeout = 20
    dump file = /tmp/freetds-resp.log
    instance = MSSQLSERVER  
    use ntlmv2 = yes


=========================================
tsql -C:
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes

=========================================
odbcinst --version:
unixODBC 2.2.14
```

---

Perl connection info:

```
$respdsn="dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=10.20.30.40;".
"UID=$respdbuser;PWD=$respdbpw;Database=r4w_004";
$respdbh=DBI->connect($respdsn);
```

I can connect to the database by using tsql at the command line. 
But using Perl I get this error:

```
DBI connect('Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=10.19.1.3;UID=gilson\mwreports;PWD=MR4gilson;Database=r4w_004','',...) failed:
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default 
driver specified (SQL-IM002) at /home/chuck/perl/gilson/jimv/fedex/fedex.pl line 1557.
 at /usr/lib/perl5/DBI.pm line 691.
        DBI::__ANON__[/usr/lib/perl5/DBI.pm:744](undef, undef) called at /usr/lib/perl5/DBI.pm line 747
```

---

My questions:

- Is the "{SQL Native Client}" in the Perl connection string correct? Does it refer to an entry in the odbc.ini or freetds.conf file?
- What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that you are missing the server port or instance in your connection string. You just specify the SQL Server itself. Do other connections work on your machine? By the way, if your using Linux try to disable SELinux, I normally had the experience that SELinux + Freetds doesn't work very well at all. :-D

Comment: To specify the instance and port in the DSN string, do I use this format? `"Server=10.20.30.40\\instance;port=1433"`. Note use of double quotes and escaped backslash, because I'm using other vars in the DSN string. Source: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-native-client-9-0-odbc-driver/

Comment: This is my dsn `$respdsn="dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=10.20.30.40\\MSSQLSERVER;".
"UID=$respdbuser;PWD=$respdbpw;Database=r4w_004;Port=1433";` and I got the same errors. Where is it trying to get the data source name from?

Comment: Try: `$respdsn="dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=10.20.30.40,1443;". "UID=$respdbuser;PWD=$respdbpw;Database=r4w_004";` Additionally try to disable SELinux.

Comment: What's SELinux and how do I disable it?

Comment: I just noticed that when I do `perl -MDBI -e 'DBI->installed_versions;'` I get this error: `DBD::Proxy      : install_driver(Proxy) failed: Can't locate RPC/PlClient.pm in @INC (you may need to install the RPC::PlClient module)`. Could this be a problem?

Comment: When I connect this way: `$respdbh=DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:responsebdo',
'gilson\mwreports', 'MR4gilson',
{AutoCommit=>0, RaiseError=>0, PrintError=>0}
);` it connects and I don't get an error, but then $respdb->errstr is undefined, and when I do `if ($respdbh->errstr)`,  I get an error about an undefined $respdbh->errstr.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FreeTDS, then your Driver is FreeTDS not "Sql Native Client".

Try this line to get your database handle:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver=FreeTDS;Server=10.20.30.40;database=r4w_004", $respdbuser, $respdbpw);
```

Comment: Is the driver name 'FreeTDS' set up in /etc/odbcinst.ini, or is it a fixed string that the system looks for?

Comment: It's set up in odbcinst.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I using tsql works normally but using perl with dbi didn't. I lost many hours trying to figure out the problem, so I saw the limitations of Adaptive Server:

- The name **cannot be more than 30 characters long**.
- The first character must be a letter (ASCII a through z, A through Z).
- The characters that follow must be letters, numbers, or underscores (_).

... So I tried to change the password that was 32 characters long to 30 characters and it works.

The tsql accept long password but perl dbi sybase accept ony 30 characters.

> Command to connect to default instance on port 1433:

```
perl -e 'use DBI;DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=10.0.0.1","sa","max_30_characters_longpassword");'
```

> Command to connect to named instance (use port udp 1434 to discover the port):

```
perl -e 'use DBI;DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=10.0.0.1\\SQL2014","sa","max_30_characters_longpassword");'
```

> Command to connect to named instance when you know the port that sqlserver is listening:

```
perl -e 'use DBI;DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=10.0.0.1:60036","sa","max_30characters_long_password");'
```

I used the tcpdump to monitoring the connection to the sqlserver:

```
tcpdump -qn dst host 10.0.0.1 &
```

Maybe it helps someone. Thanks